# Linux: batch filename change adding creation date

Tags: linux, bash, directory

i have a directory with a lot of sub-directories including files.
For each WAV file i would like to rename WAV file by adding creation date (date when file WAV has been firstly created) at the beginning of the file (without changing timestamps of file itself).

Next step would be to convert the WAV file to MP3 file, so i will save hard drive space.

for that purpose, i'm trying to create a bash script but i'm having some issues.

I want to keep the same structure as original directory and therefore i was thinking of something like:

```
for file in `ls -1 *.wav`
  do name=`stat -c %y $file | awk -F"." '{ print $1 }' | sed -e "s/\-//g" -e "s/\://g" -e "s/[ ]/_/g"`.wav
  cp -r --preserve=timestampcp $dir_original/$file $dir_converted/$name
done
```

Comment: there are only "the time of last data access, the time of last data modification, and the time the file status last changed". Which one you need?

Comment: `for file in *.wav` will do, you don't need need the backticks and ls.

Comment: re-read `man stat` and other `stat` documentation. You should be able to generate the date-string you want without all the `awk ..| sed ..` stuff. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ls` to generate a list of file names, just let the shell glob them (that's what `ls *.wav` does anyway):

```
for file in ./*.wav ; do
```

I think you want the timestamp in the format `YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS` ?
You could use GNU `date` with `stat` to have a somewhat neater control of the output format:

```
epochtime=$(stat -c %Y "$file" )
name=$(date -d "@$epochtime" +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).wav
```

`stat -c %Y` (or `%y`) gives the last modification date, but you can't really get the date of the file creation on Linux systems.

That `cp` looks ok, except for the stray `cp` at the end of `timestampcp`, but that must be a typo. If you do `*.wav`, the file names will be relative to current directory anyway, so no need to prefix with `$dir_original/`.

If you want to walk through a whole subdirectory, use Bash's `globstar` feature, or `find`. Something like this:

```
shopt -s globstar
cd "$sourcedir"
for file in ./**/*.wav ; do
    epochtime=$(stat -c %Y "$file" )
    name=$(date -d "@$epochtime" +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).wav
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    mkdir -p "$target/$dir"
    cp -r --preserve=timestamp "$file" "$target/$dir/$name"
done
```

The slight inconvenience here is that `cp` can't create the directories in the path, so we need to use `mkdir` there. Also, I'm not sure if you wanted to keep the original filename as part of the resulting one, this would remove it and just replace the file names with the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimenting with the calculation of `name` to see if I could get it more succinctly, and came up with this:

`name=$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" -r "$file")`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to append all file names in that folder with the date they were created , and below works perfectly.

```
#############################
#!/bin/sh
for file in `ls *.JPG`;
do
mv -f "$file" "$(date -r "$file" +"%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S")_"$file".jpg"
done
##############################
```